# Is there a better way of grouping by state while looping through a JSON obj?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I may be overcomplicating this. Isn't there a much simpler way of grouping by state?

```
var mutableData = [...jsonobj.data].map(({ city, state }) => ({ city, state }));
mutableData.sort(({ city: first }, { city: second }) =>
  first > second ? 1 : -1
);

var groupedCities = mutableData.reduce((acc, { city, state }) => {
  acc[state] = acc[state] || [];
  acc[state].push(city);
  return acc;
}, {});

for (key in groupedCities) {
  console.log(key);
  for (const locations in groupedCities[key]) {
    let location = groupedCities[key][locations];
    console.log(location);
  }
}
```

I created a functioning pen that outputs what I need. Just looking for an alternative method: https://codepen.io/SimplyMarkB/pen/oNwNEbz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to create a deep copy of the `data` objects since they don't get mutated - only the array gets mutated, which can be done with a plain `.slice`.

`localeCompare` is a bit more appropriate for taking the lexicographic difference between two strings and outputting a number.

Using `reduce` when the accumulator is always the same is [arguably not all that appropriate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg) and can result in unnecessarily long and verbose code.

Conditional assignment can be accomplished a bit cleaner with `??= []`.

```
const sorted = jsonobj.data.slice().sort((a, b) => a.city.localeCompare(b.city));
const grouped = {};
for (const { city, state } of sorted) {
  grouped[state] ??= [];
  grouped[state].push(city);
}
```

```js
let jsonobj = {
  current_page: 1,
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      location: "New York City",
      address1: "1313 Mockingbird Lane",
      address2: "",
      city: "New York City",
      state: "New York",
      zip: "10018",
      path: "/state/newyork/newyork"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      location: "Albany",
      address1: "1200 North 5th Street",
      address2: "Suite 4",
      city: "Albany",
      state: "New York",
      zip: "12345",
      path: "/state/newyork/albany"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      location: "Los Angelas",
      address1: "3300 Scottsdale Hwy",
      address2: "Suite 100",
      city: "Los Angelas",
      state: "California",
      zip: "90210",
      path: "/state/california/losangelas"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      location: "Toledo",
      address1: "2050 Chappel Drive",
      address2: "",
      city: "Toledo",
      state: "Ohio",
      zip: "43551",
      path: "/state/ohio/toledo"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      location: "Yonkers",
      address1: "2200 South Broadway",
      address2: "Suite 401",
      city: "Yonkers",
      state: "New York",
      zip: "45069",
      path: "/state/newyork/yonkers"
    }
  ],
  total: 5
};

const sorted = jsonobj.data.slice().sort((a, b) => a.city.localeCompare(b.city));
const grouped = {};
for (const { city, state } of sorted) {
  grouped[state] ??= [];
  grouped[state].push(city);
}

let resultDiv = document.getElementById("directory");

let htmlOutput = '<div class="container"><div id="listingbox">';
htmlOutput += '<span class="listingbox-title"><h3>Locations by State</h3></span>';

for (key in grouped) {
  htmlOutput += '<div><strong>' + key + "</strong></div>";
  htmlOutput += '<div>';
  htmlOutput += "<ul>";
  // ----- get the cities by state ----->>
  for (const centers in grouped[key]) {
    let center = grouped[key][centers];
    htmlOutput += "<li>" + center + "</li>";
  }
  // ----- /get the cities by state ----->>
  htmlOutput += "</ul>";
  htmlOutput += "</div>";
}

htmlOutput += "</div>";
resultDiv.innerHTML = htmlOutput;
```

```html
<div id="directory"></div>
```

Also, when iterating at the end, you can get both the key and the value at once with `Object.entries` instead of having to go through the key each time.

```
for (const [key, cities] in Object.entries(groupedCities)) {
  console.log(key);
  for (const city in cities) {
    console.log(city[locations]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully for what I was trying to do!! Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test if this exactly covers your case, but what I do know is you're definately overcomplicating this.

```
let states = {}

json.data.forEach(({ city, state })=>{
    states[state] = [...states[state], city]
})

for (state in states) {
    states[state] = states[state].sort()
}
```

Also, doesnt `[...jsonobj.data] == jsonobj.data` ?